# How to load field configurations in code

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I have defined fields using the UI, and some more fields using YAML files in my custom module, e.g.:

The field storage is defined in `field.storage.node.my_heading`:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - my_module
id: node.my_heading
field_name: my_heading
entity_type: node
type: string
settings: {  }
module: core
locked: false
cardinality: 1
translatable: true
indexes: {  }
persist_with_no_fields: false
custom_storage: false
```

The field instance (which attaches a field to an entity) is defined in `field.field.node.my_content_type.my_heading`:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.my_heading
    - node.type.my_content_type
id: node.my_content_type.my_heading
field_name: my_heading
entity_type: node
bundle: my_content_type
label: 'Heading'
description: 'An optional heading'
required: false
translatable: true
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings: {  }
field_type: string
```

After installing this custom module, how do I get the field configuration in code?

Answer (score 16):

The terminology is a bit confusing (as usual with Drupal), but here goes:

Field storage configurations are defined by [FieldStorageConfig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!src!Entity!FieldStorageConfig.php/class/FieldStorageConfig/8.2.x). To load one, do this:

```
$field = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_storage_config')->load('node.my_field');
```

Field instance configurations are defined by [FieldConfig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!src!Entity!FieldConfig.php/class/FieldConfig/8.2.x). To load one, do this:

```
$field_instance = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_config')->load('node.my_content_type.my_field');
```

Comment: Helpful.
How to read the field default value?

Comment: @RajeshVishwakarma The default value is part of the field instance configuration. The code to load that is shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is shorter version for @rudolfbyker's answer

For field storage:

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;

$field = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('node', 'my_field');
```

For field instance:

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;

$field_instance = FieldConfig::loadByName('node', 'my_content_type', 'my_field');
```

Those `loadByName()` static methods are actually wrappers to logic from @rudolfbyker's answer.